# Regular Expression in Java: Validating user input

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate user input using a regular expression in a while loop. I am trying to accept only one lower-case word (letters a-z inclusive).

```
public class testRedex{

    public static void main(String [] args){    
         Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);      
         System.out.print("Please enter a key: ");      
         while(!console.hasNext("[a-z]+")){                 
              System.out.println("Invalid key");            
              console.next();           
         }

         String test = console.next();          
         System.out.println(test);          
    }
}
```

My question is, is there any difference between having the regular expression as "[a-z]+" and "[a-z]+$"? I know that $ will look for a character between a-z at the end of the string, but in this case would it matter?

Comment: give a sample of accepted input.

Comment: Some examples would be words like "cat, fish, dog, sjakjsdljasmx, five, regularexpresson, etc."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a difference, if you'll use: `^[a-z]+$` it means that whatever the user inputs should be combined only from `[a-z]+`.

If you don't add the `^` and the `$` the user could insert other characters, space for example, and there will still be a match (the first part of the string until the space.

Let's see an example:

- run your code with the input: "try this" (it'll print "try")
- now change the regex to `^[a-z]+$` and run with the same input (it'll print "Invalid key").

The way I would re-write it is:

```
    System.out.print("Please enter a key: ");

    String test = console.nextLine();
    while (!test.matches("^[a-z]+$")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid key");
        test = console.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: @alfasin Okay, thanks for the update. Do you know why the hasNext() method does not work properly with the regular expression "^[a-z]+$"?

Comment: @user3808889 it's not that it doesn't work with the regex: in the original version `hasNext()` was used right after the call to `nextLine()` (at the end of the loop) and that caused the mess.

Answer (score 0):

The difference are as follows

`[a-z]+` means a,b,c,...,or z occurs more than one time

`[a-z]+$` means a,b,c,...,or z occurs more that one time and must match end of the line

Yet at the end, they give you **the same result**.

if you want to understand it better try this

```
([A-Z])([a-z]+$)
```

It start with a capital letter and end with more than one time small letter

output:

```
Please enter a key: AAAAaaaa
Invalid key
Aaaaaa
Aaaaaa
```

Another way you can get the expected result from what you are looking for

code:

```
    int i = 0;
    String result = "";
    do{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your key:");

    if(input.hasNext("^[a-z]+$")){
        result = input.next();
        i=1;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid key"); 
    }
   }while(i==0);
    System.out.println("the result is " + result);
```

output:

```
Enter your key:
HHHh
Invalid key
Enter your key:
Hellllo
Invalid key
Enter your key:
hello
the result is hello
```